# How can I show only the first <a> in a loop and hide all other elements?

Tags: php

I am using a function

```
function recursiveArrayToList($array = array()){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            echo '<li><a href="#">' . $key . '</a>';
            if (is_array($value)) {
                recursiveArrayToList($value);
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo recursiveArrayToList($array);
```

that creates a ul list.

I want to hide all elements EXCEPT the first `<a>`. This should be displayed.

I used this solution to detect the first element:

```
function recursiveArrayToList($array = array()){
    $first = true;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ( $first )
        {
           echo "first element, that should be shown";
           $first = false;
        }
        else
        {
           echo "all other elements that should be hidden";
        }
        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $key . '</a>';
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recursiveArrayToList($value);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
echo recursiveArrayToList($array);
```

But now all my elements that do have children get the text "first element that should be shown" not only the first element as expected.

---

I made a mistake in my question, so to be very clear I will show here what I need:

```
<ul><---- Show only this element
    <li>farm 
        <ul><---- Do not show
            <li>animals</li>
                <ul><---- Do not show
                    <li>horses</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>fred</li>
                            <li>sam</li>
                            <li>alan</li>
                            <li>john</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my script:

```
<script>

$(window).load(function(){
    $('li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
        ullist.slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In your recursion, calling `recursiveArrayToList()` again will set $first to true again in that context.

Comment: Add a `class` who's style is a `display: none;` to the `li` you want to hide?

Comment: You can add a parameter to `recursiveArrayToList` called `$first = true` (example: `recursiveArrayToList($array = array(), $first = true)`) and when you call it recursively pass `false` instead of the default `true`

Comment: @PatrickGregorio But it is a loop, if I put a class to one `li`, I put a class to all `li`s

Comment: @AlonEitan Eitan I didn't get exactly how you mean it

Comment: @Jarla Check my answer below to only add a class except the first element.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio I will test it now

Comment: @Jarla just make sure to only set the `$first` variable to `false` AFTER you `echo` the `li` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

#### PHP

```
$class = !$first ? "class='hidden'" : "";
echo '<li ' . $class . '><a href="#">' . $key . '</a>';
$first = false;
```

#### EDIT

Overall this is what you should have:

```
function recursiveArrayToList($array = array(), $first = true){
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $class = !$first ? "class='hidden'" : "";
    echo '<li ' . $class . '><a href="#">' . $key . '</a>';
    $first = false;
    if (is_array($value)) {
      recursiveArrayToList($value, false);
    }
    echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
echo recursiveArrayToList($array);
```

Comment: I tested it, now everything is hidden

Comment: Remove the `$first = false;` inside your `if` statement.

Comment: `<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<?php
function recursiveArrayToList($array = array()){
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $class = !$first ? "class='hidden'" : "";
  echo '<li ' . $class . '><a href="#">' . $key . '</a>';
  $first = false;
  if (is_array($value)) {
   recursiveArrayToList($value);
  }
  echo '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
}
echo recursiveArrayToList($array);`

Comment: the result is everything is hidden

Comment: Where did your `$first = true;` statement go?

Comment: @Jarla I've updated my answer to include the entire function.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio Please note that the recursive call to the function will NOT output `class='hidden'` in first `<li>`s of the sub `<ul>`s because of the `$first = true;` on the second line in the function

Comment: @AlonEitan I was given the impression that the first `li` of a sub `ul` should be considered a `first` item according to the way OP detects the first element.

Comment: Hummm... Well I'm not sure. Let's let the OP rule about this :)

Comment: I think it is working now! Thank you! but unfortunately I see that I made a mistake in my question :'( I need to hide all elements except the parent <ul>, I tried to fix it working with your code, but it seems to be more complex:

Comment: function recursiveArrayToList($array = array()){
  $first = true;
  $class = !$first ? "class='hidden'" : "";
 echo '<ul ' . $class . '>';
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo '<li><a href="#">' . $key . '</a>';
  $first = false;
  if (is_array($value)) {
   recursiveArrayToList($value);
  }
  echo '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
}
echo recursiveArrayToList($array);

Comment: @Jarla, if you're only supposed to display the absolute first `li` and hide the first `li` of any sub `ul` then use a combination of me and @Alon Eitan's answer.

Comment: Essentially you would want to apply a `class` like how I did here. But to determine which is first you would have to use @Alon's approach of passing by reference.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I updated my question to be very clear

Comment: @Jarla I've updated my answer again to use a combination of me and Alon's answers. Kindly check again.

Comment: @AlonEitan If I remove that statement and the second `li` is not an `array` it will be marked as a first item.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio: Thank you, it looks very well! Only my first ul is displayed, everything else is hidden. My jQuery code is not working anymore (I posted above) but this is another issue, I need to check now! Thanks for the kind help

Comment: @Jarla happy to help. Also thanks to Alon for pointing out that my assumption was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter by reference that will indicate if it's the current first element:

```
function recursiveArrayToList($array = array(), &$first){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ( $first )
        {
           echo "first element, that should be shown";
           $first = false;
        }
        else
        {
           echo "all other elements that should be hidden";
        }
        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $key . '</a>';
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recursiveArrayToList($value, $first);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
$first = true;
echo recursiveArrayToList($array, $first);
```

Note that I passed `$first` by reference (hence the `&` before the parameter name) - This mean that changes in the value of this parameters inside the function will save to the original `$first` that was declared outside the function scope.

Alternative solution, use a default parameter value to the `$first` variable:

```
function recursiveArrayToList($array = array(), $first = true){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ( $first )
        {
           echo "first element, that should be shown";
           $first = false; // You can comment out this line in order to allow the display of all the first "<li>" on the first level
        }
        else
        {
           echo "all other elements that should be hidden";
        }
        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $key . '</a>';
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recursiveArrayToList($value, false);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

echo recursiveArrayToList($array);
```

Now, when you're calling `recursiveArrayToList` on the first time, the `$first` is true by default, and the recursive call is passing `false` to prevent outputting the string.

Comment: @Jarla Cool! I added another solution - To show alternative approach for this

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! Unfortunately I found out that I made a mistake in my question, so I need to hide all elements except the parent <ul>.

Comment: @Jarla Just edited my answer - see which line you need to comment out in order to get it to work (On the second version of the solution)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help!